# Setting iOS Navigation background color not working correctly

Tags: ios, swift

I have a very specific issue. When I set the background `barTintColor` to my blue, it's too light. Nothing I do seems to make it 100% accurate.

So I changed the code to set the nav bar background to 100% black. Using the OS X app SIP to analyze the color, or just setting the view to black as well, it's pretty obvious the color is very dark gray, but not black.

What is making the tint color screw up? As it stands, the blue I need and what the nav bar is showing are not the same.

```
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.imageFromColor(UIColor.black), for: .default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()

    navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .blackOpaque
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isOpaque = true
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
```

Also in a blank project, fresh, same issue.

Comment: Have you tried to set `navigationBar.isOpaque` to `true` ?

Comment: I did, same result. Literally no change. I updated the sample code. Also in a blank project, fresh, same issue.

Comment: It appears that the navigation bar contains a blur, that's the reason why you can't get the color that you want. Create a custom navigation bar, it has been always the solution for me.

Comment: I was about ready to do just that, but Marian below got it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key is to set `isTranslucent` to `false`.

```
let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar
navigationBar?.barTintColor = .black
navigationBar?.isTranslucent = false
```

Comment: Holy crap, thank you. It was the translucent setting. Literally crawled all over SO trying to find this answer. Good job.